# How can I kickstart a group advocating digital literacy with Ubuntu?

Tags: community, locoteams

I'm currently working in a cyber cafe in Cameroon, Africa. Desktop penetration is very low here, so I wish to create a grassroots organisation with my mates to promote ICT. Where can I find materials and people interested in the project "Promote Computer Literacy and Digital Literacy with Ubuntu"?

Answer (score 1):

If you can provide transportation for the shipment FOB Portland, Oregon, you could apply for a grant from a 501(c)(3) not-for-profit organization, FreeGeek.Org. See http://www.freegeek.org/about/grants for details.

Answer (score 0):

Due to Customs issues this would be very difficult to achieve from scratch.

- As you can see even System76 don't ship there: https://www.system76.com/home/shippinginformation/

Actually you need to find an African import company that can provide you with components (Motherborads, GPUs, RAM, HDD, Cases, .....). Mount machines and install/tweak ubuntu on them. Contact the Commerce Chamber in your city to get a list of any existing suppliers.

- In another hand you can start by going through a partnership program with a company like Dell as a resseler or redistributor:
  http://partnerdirect.dell.com/sites/channel/fr_cm/Partner-Programme-Information/GlobalCommercialEmergingChannel/Pages/GlobalCommercialEmergingChannel.aspx

Comment: Thank's for the reply but after months of searching over the INTERNET without successful results i have decide to start with some basics workshops for the mass in BASICS internet <WITH GOOGLE PRODUCTS > hopping I CAN GET in touch with volunteers that can help us set a computer lab with LTSP UBUNTU.
please if there are people interested about the project feel free to contact me.